# elasticsearch phrase suggester java api

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, search-suggestion

The PhraseSuggestionBuilder in 1.6.0 of the elasticsearch java API has a collateQuery method that takes a String.

```
builder
  .collateQuery("\"match\": {\"title\" : \"{{suggestion}}\"}")
  .collatePrune(true);
```

Unfortunately the escaped quotes are escaped by the builder to produce JSON like this:

```
"collate" : {
    "query" : "\"match\": {\"title\" : \"{{suggestion}}\"}",
    "prune" : true
 }
```

Anyone any ideas how I can stop this String being escaped as the JSON is generated?

Thanks.

Comment: I ended up using the RestTemplate pattern and not using the Java API at all.  Digging though the 1.6.0 elasticsearch code, I can't see how to avoid the double escaping of the collate query.
`String text = String.format(config.getQueryTemplate(), query.getText().toLowerCase());
        String url = addTypes(getIndexUrl(), types) + "/_search";
        try {
            return rest.postForObject(url, text, String.class);
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            LOG.error("Unable to search: {}", e.getResponseBodyAsString(), e);
            throw e;
        }`